# After submitting the form the react-select dropdown not clear it's value

Tags: reactjs, react-select

In my code, I am using  *react-select* (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) . What I want to do is after clicking the submit button, I want to remove the selected value.

The code I used is shown below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Select from 'react-select'


class App extends Component {

    clearDataAuto() {
            const { change } = this.props;
            change('letterType','null')
    }

    onAutoLetterSubmit() {
        /* ......*/
        this.clearDataAuto();
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Field name="letterType" component="input" type="hidden"></Field>
    <Select 
            options={letterTypesArray && letterTypesArray.map(letterTypeObj => (
            {
               value: letterTypeObj.TypeID,
               label: letterTypeObj.Type
            }
            ))

           } 
           onChange={(e)=>{change('letterType', e.value);}}
        /> 
    <button  onClick={this.onAutoLetterSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {

    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {

    };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

When I used normal `<select>` and `<option>` tags instead of `react-select` the above code worked well.

Now can anybody help me to clear the data from react-select drop down after clicking the Submit button?

Comment: Putting your code working in https://codesandbox.io/ or an alternative would make it easier to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value in `Select` tag and clear the value `onClick` of submit button.

Here I guess your value will be stored in variable `letterType` of `props`.

```
<Select
  options={letterTypesArray && letterTypesArray.map(letterTypeObj => ({
    value: letterTypeObj.TypeID,
    label: letterTypeObj.Type
  }))}
  value={this.props.letterType}
  onChange={(e) => { change('letterType', e.value); }}
/>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: the value isn't stored in variable `letterType` of `props`. `value` and `label` are taken from the array collection called `letterTypesArray`

Comment: But you have to store selected value somewhere in state and assign same variable in `Select` tag then and then it will work.